# How to parse JSON string into Android as an Array?

Tags: php, android, json

A very simple question, a lot of examples out there, but none of them worked for me.

I need to parse the simplest form of a json string :

```
{"id" : "5" , "name" : "John"}
```

How do I turn this into an array, list, map whatever, so that I can get something like this ?

```
myArray["id"] = 5
```

Comment: In which language (for android) you pass string as index of array?

Comment: to parse  in android   `JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject("mystring");
    String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
    String anem = jsonobject.getString("name");`

Comment: @Raghunandan your solution worked for me. Thanks for this. Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse json

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject("mystring");
String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
String anem = jsonobject.getString("name");
```

Once you parser and get the data add it to array or a list or use a DataHolder like blackbelt suggested

Comment: how did you understand that he wants to know how to parse a json?

Comment: @blackbelt i was confused as you were so i posted it as a comment. now he left me a comment to post it as an answer and said it helped. should i delete this answer now?

Comment: no no, you should leave since it fixes the po issue.. my comment was only to point out that sometimes, in the android tag, answer a question is only wild guess or, at least, I feel this way

Comment: @blackbelt i agree i made a guess as i was not sure what he wanted. that's why i left it as a comment at the start. only after he mentioned it helped and asked me to post it as answer i did.

Comment: cool dude, it was just to share some kind of awkward feeling :D

Comment: @blackbelt I wrote it on the question title :) and I thought the question was clear, but I forgot to add Java as the tag. sorry about that..

Comment: @mobilGelistirici all the same is unclear. Because the body and code in your question were talking about something different

Comment: @blackbelt no problem your comments help me learn and provide good answers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be

```
  public class DataHolder {
      String id;
      String name;
    }

    ArrayList<DataHolder> dataHolder = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();

    while (parsing) {
      holder = new DataHolder();
      holder.name = name;
      holder.id = id;
      dataHolder.add(holder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JSONObject rawData = new JSONObject("{\"id\" : \"5\" , \"name\" : \"John\"}");
        Iterator<String> keys = rawData.keys();
        HashMap<String, String> mappedData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (keys.hasNext())
        {
            String key = (String) keys.next();

            if(rawData.getString(key) != null && rawData.getString(key)!= null)
            {
                mappedData.put(key, rawData.getString(key));
            }
        }
```

Now you can get data as

```
mappedData.get("id"); // 5
mappedData.get("name") // John
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://x.x.x.x/JSON/";


//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

JSONArray user = null;

 // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

           }
        catch(Exception e)
          { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
```